# Getting innerHTML from 3 URLs - Asynchronous Problems

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the innerHTML of a DIV tag from 3 URLs but it looks like the response is too quick.

I want the innerHTML from a DIV tag and to put it into an object and another DIV tag in my HTML document.

This is what I have so far:

```
var chNumber = "11885705";
var chPageOne;
var chPageTwo;
var chPageThree;

const urls = [
    'https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/' + chNumber,
    'https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/' + chNumber + '/officers',
    'https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/' + chNumber + '/persons-with-significant-control'
];



    // map every url to the promise of the fetch
    let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url));
    
    // Promise.all waits until all jobs are resolved
    Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .catch(err => err)))
    .then(results => {      

        // Initialize the DOM parser
        var parser = new DOMParser();

        // Parse the text
        var doc1 = parser.parseFromString(results[0], "text/html");
        var doc2 = parser.parseFromString(results[1], "text/html");
        var doc3 = parser.parseFromString(results[2], "text/html");

        // You can now even select part of that html as you would in the regular DOM 
        // Example:
        
        chPageOne = doc1.getElementById('content-container').innerHTML;
        chPageTwo = doc2.getElementById('content-container').innerHTML;
        chPageThree = doc3.getElementById('content-container').innerHTML;

        document.getElementById('holdingAreaOne').innerHTML = chPageOne;
        document.getElementById('holdingAreaTwo').innerHTML = chPageTwo;
        document.getElementById('holdingAreaThree').innerHTML = chPageThree;

        //console.log(chPageOne);
        //console.log(chPageTwo);
        //console.log(chPageThree);

    })
    


        
        var companyName = chPageOne.getElementsByClassName("heading-xlarge")[0].innerText;
```

The (first) error I get is about this last line:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined

Is this because I've messed up the promise??? I think it gets to this line before the above has had a chance to complete.

This is my first attempt at javascript, so be as brutal as you want.

Maybe a simpler question is how can I get the innerHTML of the div id 'content-container' from those 3 urls so I can use the HTML later?

Thanks a million,

Dave.

Comment: Side note; why are you mapping your fetches twice?

Comment: The getElementsByClassName error is due to promises being asynchronous.  The variable will not have a result yet when you try to access it outside of the promise.

Comment: Move the last line *inside* the callback function.

Comment: If I move it inside the callback I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined

As for mapping them twice, I know what you mean, but dont know how to map it only once! This is my first-ish attempt at javascript, and this has grown arms and legs. I'm changing an existing project from VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. `promise` is a async, so you'll need get your variables within it's callback function
2. `chPageOne` is a string, not element object.

Fixing these issues:

```
var chNumber = "11885705";
var chPageOne;
var chPageTwo;
var chPageThree;

const urls = [
  'https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/' + chNumber,
  'https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/' + chNumber + '/officers',
  'https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/' + chNumber + '/persons-with-significant-control'
];



// map every url to the promise of the fetch
// let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url)); //don't need this

// Promise.all waits until all jobs are resolved
Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .catch(err => console.error(err))))
  .then(results => {

    // Initialize the DOM parser
    var parser = new DOMParser();

    // Parse the text
    var doc1 = parser.parseFromString(results[0], "text/html");
    var doc2 = parser.parseFromString(results[1], "text/html");
    var doc3 = parser.parseFromString(results[2], "text/html");

    // You can now even select part of that html as you would in the regular DOM 
    // Example:

    chPageOne = doc1.getElementById('content-container');
    chPageTwo = doc2.getElementById('content-container');
    chPageThree = doc3.getElementById('content-container');

    document.getElementById('holdingAreaOne').innerHTML = chPageOne.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('holdingAreaTwo').innerHTML = chPageTwo.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('holdingAreaThree').innerHTML = chPageThree.innerHTML;

    var companyName = chPageOne.getElementsByClassName("heading-xlarge")[0].innerText;
    console.log(companyName)
    //console.log(chPageOne);
    //console.log(chPageTwo);
    //console.log(chPageThree);

  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```